# How to ignore the margin inline blocks create with different heights?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an issue where the blocks stack by 2, and the next 2 blocks start at the end of the first 2 blocks. As shown in [this JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rezf2mbs/1/).

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inline">
  A div with less content than that one >
  </div>
  <div class="inline">
  A div with more content than the one on the left. Now Inline 3 goes down to where this div ends. I want to move it up however, so it's right under the div that's above Inline 3.
  </div>
  <div class="inline">
  Inline 3
  </div>
  <div class="inline">
  Inline 4
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  width:600px;
  background-color:rgb(40,40,40);
}

.inline {
  width:calc(50% - 22px);
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  color:white;
  background-color:#e74c3c;
  text-align:center;
  margin:5px 10px;
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

**Note:** *This doesn't take up the white space created by the top-right div.*

**Expected/wanted output**:

[image: Expected output]

**Note:** *This does make use of the whitespace.*

I'm aware that this is possible with 2 columns, but I don't want to use 2 columns. Because I must be able to remove some div's without having unequal content in the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem at the website i created. i used masonry to solve that:
http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `column-count` property,

be aware the items will be ordered in column descending order.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rezf2mbs/5/)

Comment: The positioning is okay, but I don't want the items to be re-ordered. It will be confusing as the content is created dynamically, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/rezf2mbs/11/

Comment: Couldn't this be applied based on rows, instead of columns?

Comment: have you tried masonry?

Comment: Trying it now @maioman

Answer (score 0):

Make the div with more content float to the right by adding a second class to it.

**HTML**

```
<div class="inline right">
  A div with more content than the one on the left. Now Inline 3 goes 
  down to where this div ends. I want to move it up however, so it's 
  right under the div that's above Inline 3.
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rezf2mbs/12/)